# Xcode error: ld: library not found for -lgomp

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios4

I'm compiling a project in Objective-C depending on libraries in C.

The compilation fails with the following error:

```
Ld /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyProject-enqkiqdfplxedfeowxlkwfgadtyz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp.app/MyApp normal i386

cd /Users/user/Documents/XCodeWorkspace/MyProject/Subproject

setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.6

setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/clang -arch i386 -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk -L/Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyProject-enqkiqdfplxedfeowxlkwfgadtyz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -L/Users/user/Documents/XCodeWorkspace/MyProject/Subproject/../../../../../Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyProject-enqkiqdfplxedfeowxlkwfgadtyz/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -F/Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyProject-enqkiqdfplxedfeowxlkwfgadtyz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -filelist /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyProject-enqkiqdfplxedfeowxlkwfgadtyz/Build/Intermediates/MyProject.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp.build/Objects-normal/i386/MyApp.LinkFileList -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -fopenmp -licucore -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -D__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED=40300 -lamsip -lcares -lexosip2 -lgsm -lmediastreamer2 -lspeex -lsrtp -lsqlite3.0 -framework MessageUI -framework AudioToolbox -framework AVFoundation -lz -framework AddressBook -framework AddressBookUI -framework Foundation -framework UIKit -framework CoreGraphics -framework SystemConfiguration -framework CoreTelephony -lTestFlight -o /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyProject-enqkiqdfplxedfeowxlkwfgadtyz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp.app/MyApp

ld: library not found for -lgomp

Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1
```

The problem I see is that this library isn't even specified in the link command! Why is this needed at all?

Yours,
Emmanuel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone had enabled OpenMP using "other flags" which causes the -lgomp library to be included. :-(